# Вопрос по поводу графа

Tags: c++, graph

Мне  нужно в моем класе Node иметь  узел на вершину что сосед с текущей вершиной  и расстояние между ними то есть вес ребра. Как мне  это все  записать? я  не  знаю((

Мой  код:

```
 struct Node 
 {
   public:
      Node(int x, Node* node);
   private:
      int mX;
      Node* mNode;
 };
```

как я  написала.  но я  не уверена правильно ли я  написала

Comment: не могли бы приложить кусок проблемного кода, чтобы было ясно как нужно ответить. на абстактные вопросы очень сложно отвечать.

Comment: @ Senior Pomidor скинула свой код, как я  сделала. но я не увернеа в нем(((

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что вы реализуете граф и вам нужно хранить узлы потомков и родителя?

Comment: @Senior Pomidor не совсем.  мне  нужно в класе Node делать. у меня есть вершина. мне  нужно  знать  какая  следущая вершина(указател на неъ по идеее)и расстояние между ними то есть вес ребра. Не  обизательно узлы потомков и родителя. Хоча может вы правы если в   общем говорить

Comment: если mX - это расстояние, а mNode указатель на следующую вершину, то вы сделали правильно. не хватает еще методоа добавление вершин, удаление и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант выделить ребро в отдельную структуру и в ней хранить вес и указатели на узлы.
А в узле хранить указатели на все связанные с ней ребра.
Например, так:

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct Edge;

struct Node
{
public:
    Node() : m_id(-1) {}
    Node(int id) : m_id(id) {}

    int id() { return m_id; }

    list<Edge*>& get_Edges() { return m_Edges; }

private:
    int m_id;
    list<Edge*> m_Edges;
};

struct Edge
{
public:
    Edge() : m_id(-1), m_weight(0) {}
    Edge(const int id, const int weight) : m_id(id), m_weight(weight) {}

    int id() const { return m_id; }

    int get_weight() const { return m_weight; }
    void set_weight(int weight) { m_weight = weight; }

    Node* get_first_node() { return m_first_node; }
    Node* get_second_node() { return m_second_node; }

    void set_first_node(Node* node) { m_first_node = node; }
    void set_second_node(Node* node) { m_second_node = node; }

private:
    int m_id;
    int m_weight;
    Node* m_first_node;
    Node* m_second_node;
};
```

И всем этим хозяйством манипулировать через свой класс Graph.

В зависимости от контекста использования графа ребра можно хранить либо в vector, либо в list. Последнее предпочтительно в случае постоянно изменяющегося графа.

Comment: я писала свой клас Graph и я только   int значения  записывала в граф. а если я  например  захочу string, float. Как  лутче  шаблон анписать чтобы  он для всех  типов  походил. в  list использовать или vector?

Comment: Структуру Node делаете шаблонной, в нее, соответственно, поле шаблонного типа. Класс Graph тоже делаете шаблонным, для типизации узлов. По поводу list или vector уже написал выше.
Если граф строится один раз и в последствии редко меняется, то vector.
Если в графе постоянно происходят перестроения, то list.
Вообще, в качестве универасльного решения можно воспользоваться вектором, но в конструкторе Node резервировать память. Под три связи, скажем.